# Android back-compatibility using v7 appcompat library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I have created a new android project in Eclipse, and I have setted this configuration:

```
Minimum required SDK: API 7
Target SDK: API 18
Compile with: API 18
Theme: Holo Light
```

So, my application has the actionbar. Eclipse has automatically included only android-support-v4.jar.

But, since `ActionBar class is included in the support library for compatibility with API level 7 and higher.` I am wondering why in my project are included only android-support-v4 library.

I guess that if I don't include **v7 appcompat library** I can continue to show the actionbar in my application, but I can't manage or customize it using ActionBar API? Is this right?

Comment: v7 appcompat library is not automatically included because you can have/not have resources linked to it: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html (Adding Support Libraries). You need v7 to use and customize ActionBar, if you still want to be backward compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the docs

The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

If you want your app to support action bar below 3.0 you need to use app compact v7 from the support library.

Also check the below link

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: So, if I'm setting the minimum required SDK to 7, Eclipse does not give me any error if I use Holo Light Theme and I do not include support library v7?

Comment: @Joseph82 on what version did you test. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html.

Comment: I have not already tested for device with API level < 11, but I'm talking about error at compile-time. If  I set the minimum required SDK to 7 and I do not include support library v7, simply the actionbat will not be shown in devices with API level < 11. I'm guessin right?

Comment: I guess if you have lint setup in eclipse it should warn you about the same. check through the list here http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Comment: I have just tried two devices (Android 4.2.1 and Android 2.3.3). The former show me the actionbar, while the latter does not show it. So I was guessing right.

Comment: @Joseph82 well you can also use actionbarsherlock library if you wish to support action bar prior to 3.0.

Comment: I know @Raghunandan. But I want to learn it :) I have already use ActionBarSherlok.

Comment: @Joseph82 go through the link in my post add support library and you get action bar priot to 3.0 and you can customize the same. here's a blog http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: @Raghunandan However, lint gives me: Scanning ActionBarExample: ..............
Scanning ActionBarExample (Phase 2): ........

No issues found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39147/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-joseph82)

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand some of the very basic things.

1) Support libraries are meant to support functionalities in previous versions. you need to manually setup your project(addition in build path etc) to use support libraries.

2) If you dont use support library v7 in this case, You can show action bar, can customize it and do whatever it is supported in the version(3.0) ActionBar supported in.

3) If you want to show Action Bar in suppose Api levels 8/7(2.2/2.1), you must use support libraries v7. 
[Here is how to create action bars and support it lower versions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

**Please dont forget to use/imports classes/apis from support library instead of SDKs classes.** 
Tutorial is easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

1) Support libraries are meant to support functionalities in previous versions **and add functionalities that only exists in these libraries**. You need to manually setup your project(addition in build path etc) to use support libraries.